# Location of customized rspec scaffold spec files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to customize [RSpec controller spec scaffold](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/rspec/scaffold/templates/controller_spec.rb) and [RSpec model spec scaffold](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/rspec/model/templates/model_spec.rb).

To customize "RSpec controller spec scaffold" => I put my file in `lib/templates/rspec/scaffold/controller_spec.rb`, and it works.

But for this one: "RSpec model spec scaffold", where should I put my customized file?

Is there any documentation on this? Can't find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct location is `lib/templates/rspec/model/model_spec.rb`. But still want to know is there any docs on this?